# A topological space with cardinality strictly less than its weight?

Tags: general-topology

My book states that

> if $X$ is compact, then $w(X) \leq |X|$.

This leads me to wonder, is there a nice example of a (non-compact) topological space where $w(x) > |X|$ holds?

The weight of a topological space is the smallest cardinality of a basis of the topology.

Comment: You want to remind us the definition of weight ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus : The weight of a topological space is the smallest cardinality of a basis of the topology.

Comment: But is it polite to question a topology about its weight

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2500413/4280) I give a proof the first fact, if you're interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The maximal weight of a space $X$ is $2^{|X|}$ and in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231320/4280) I give some examples (with proofs) of spaces that realise this maximum. E.g. a countable dense subset of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ in the product topology has weight $|\mathbb{R}|$.

The bound $w(X) \le |X|$ for compact spaces follows from the equality $nw(X) =w(X)$ for (locally) compact spaces (and it also holds for metrisable spaces and orderable spaces), so many standard examples don’t work.

Comment: +1 - this is a better answer than mine, since it provides examples of maximal weight. (I'll leave mine up anyways though.)

Comment: Interesting. So even though the weight of the discrete topology on $X$ is $|X|$, and the weight of the anti-discrete topology on $|X|$ is 1 (I think), there are topologies that are "in between" these, yet have a larger weight than both?

Comment: @theQman by convention the weight of the anti-discrete topology is $\aleph_0$ (weight is infinite by convention). But yes, the max lies in between.

Comment: 1) Why is weight infinite by convention? What if the space is finite? And how is this convention implied by the definition " minimum cardinality of a basis"? 2) What do you mean by "the max lies in between"?

Comment: @theQman That’s the way it’s defined (so some counting arguments go through) in “cardinal functions in topology” and its sequel, which form a basis for the theory. Finite spaces have weight $\aleph_0$ as well, but in papers that *only* deal with finite spaces sometimes finite cardinals are used. In that case the maximal weight is also at most $|X|$ as well, of course. Max in between refers to that the maximal weight lies between indiscrete and discrete.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the club-generated topology on $\omega_1$ is an example (a set is open in this topology iff it is a union of sets which are [unbounded and closed in the order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_set) - this does indeed form a topology, since [the intersection of two clubs is a club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_filter)). Given any $\omega_1$-sequence of open sets $C_\eta$, I can build a club (hence open) set which doesn't contain any of them, as follows:

- We begin at stage $0$ with $D_0=\emptyset$.
- At stage $\alpha+1$, pick some $\beta\in C_\alpha$ greater than $\sup(D_\alpha)$, and let $D_{\alpha+1}=D_\alpha\cup\{\beta\}$ (so since we keep adding bigger ordinals, we'll keep $\beta$ out of the club we're building). This is possible since $C_\alpha$, being a union of clubs, is unbounded.
- At stage $\lambda$ limit, let $D_\lambda=(\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} D_\alpha)\cup\{\sup(\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} D_\alpha)\}$.

Let $D=\bigcup_{\eta<\omega_1} D_\eta$. $D$ is club, hence open, and doesn't contain any of the $C_\eta$s. So $\{C_\eta:\eta<\omega_1\}$ was not a base for the club-generated topology on $\omega_1$.

---

It's worth noting that this argument **does** use a bit of choice: in the successor steps of our construction, we're assuming that there are in fact ordinals bigger than $\sup(D_\alpha)$. This uses the fact that $\omega_1$ is not a countable union of countable sets, which surprisingly [is not provable in ZF alone](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16249/28111). Interestingly, ZF *does* prove that $\omega_2$ is not a countable union of countable sets. So that's nice.

EDIT: As Asaf points out, if $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality then "club" doesn't really make sense (every singleton is now the intersection of two clubs, so the topology is discrete).

Comment: What would be the club topology on $\omega_2$ if it had cofinality $\omega$? You need *some* choice, I guess, to even make sense of the idea of a club topology.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh yeah, good point. (I think you mean $\omega_1$ ...)

Comment: (No, I meant what I meant, but also $\omega_1$, yes.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Where did I mention the club topology on $\omega_2$, though?

Comment: You haven't explicitly, but you did mention that (1) $\omega_2$ is not a countable union of countable sets (which is nice, but does not exclude it from having countable cofinality); and (2) you did originally ask about the club topology for cardinals above $\omega_1$, and might as well start with $\omega_2$ if you want to wonder about that. :)

Comment: Is it known what the weight of this topology on $\omega_1$ is? $\aleph_2$ provable in ZFC?

Comment: @Henno: Without being too fussy about it, I'd guess that (or its negation) would be equivalent to some saturation or other combinatorial property of the non-stationary ideal, and would therefore be equiconsistent with some large cardinal properties. But that's a very nice question!